# Is the iPhone magnetometer sensitive enough to detect solar storms?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware-recommendation, compass

Discovered this neat project to pull detailed magnetometer data from iOS: https://github.com/foundry/MagnetoMeter

I've been looking at different approaches to setting up a 24/7 magnetometer to monitor solar activity. One option was to set up an old iPhone 6 and beam the data over wifi to a server. However, I'm unfamiliar with the iPhone's hardware and sensitivity.

Is the built-in magnetometer going to be sensitive enough to detect solar storms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anyone here will be able to give you a definitive answer to this, unless of course they've tried to do something similar.

Apple only provides very basic specs in terms of its sensors (e.g. accelerometer, gyro, proximity, compass, barometer, etc) and doesn't go into their individual specifications.

However, considering that [anyone can build a magnetometer from easily available materials](http://static.lawrencehallofscience.org/diy_sun_science/downloads/diy_ss_detect_solar_storms.pdf) to measure slight changes in Earth’s magnetic field due to solar storms, my guess would be that an iPhone's magnetometer will pick up on these fluctuations as well. But of course, this is nothing more than an *educated guess*.